# Can't call package installed by composer

Tags: composer-php

I am trying to try this tool https://github.com/bramus/mixed-content-scan

So, I install a package through command prompt using `composer`
This is the installation command that I run: `composer global require bramus/mixed-content-scan ~2.1`

When I try to run `mixed-content-scan https://www.bram.us/` in the command prompt, it says that command is not exist yet. Why is that? What did I do wrong?

Thanks before! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just like the answer from Wondra. It's answered by the composer package owner himself.

I just need to use this on command prompt: `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\Ami\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`

More information here https://github.com/bramus/mixed-content-scan/issues/20#issuecomment-78285213

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you do not have the directory where composer symlinks the executable files in your PATH.

Add `~/.composer/vendor/bin` to your $PATH environment variable, restart your shell and try again.

Comment: Do you mean by `SET PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin`, right?

Comment: I'm not sure about the scope of that call on Windows, does it appear in your Environment variables like described here: http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/ ?